# How to shorten the syntax of passing a function as a parameter?

Tags: scala, currying

**Intro**

In an external library I'm using, the class `org.scaloid.common.TraitAdapterView` contains the function `onItemClick` defined as:

```
@scala.inline
  def onItemClick[U](
     f : scala.Function4[android.widget.AdapterView[_], 
                         android.view.View, 
                         scala.Int, 
                         scala.Long, U]) : V =
     { /* compiled code */ }
```

where V is defined at the top of the class:

```
trait TraitAdapterView[V <: android.widget.AdapterView[_]]
```

**Now to the actual question.**

I have defined the following function in my code:

```
def onClick(parent:AdapterView[_] , view:View, position:Int, id:Long) = 3
```

and I'm able to call is as

```
listView.onItemClick((a, b, c, d) => onClick(a, b, c, d))
```

but the following **doesn't** work:

```
listView.onItemClick(onClick)
```

Why? What should I change to make it work?

Comment: `onClick(_, _, _, _)` might work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `onItemClick[U]` is a `Function4`, i.e. a function taking four arguments, as detailed by the type parameters. When you write this notation:

```
(a, b, c, d) => onClick(a, b, c, d)
```

you are creating an anonymous Function4 of nearly the correct signature. I don't think this should compile. Are you sure it does? The problem is that the return type of `onClick` is `Int` while the return type expected for `onItemClick`'s argument is `V<: android.widget.AdapterView[_]` which is likely not compatible with `Int`.

When you use this notation:

```
onClick
```

you would normally be invoking a call to `onClick` and providing its results to the `onItemClick` function but since there are missing arguments, the Scala compiler should interpret it as a function reference.  Since the results of `onClick` are not compatible with the arguments of `onItemClick`, you should get an error. Could you include your compiler output for the error you got?

When you use this notation:

```
onClick _
```

you are referencing the function named `onClick` and passing it to `onItemClick`. Since `onClick` is the right kind of Function4 (assuming the result type is compatible), it should work.

For your interest, consider this REPL session:

```
scala> def foo(f: Function1[Int,Int]) : Int = f(1)
foo: (f: Int => Int)Int
scala> def bar(i: Int) : Int = 3
bar: (i: Int)Int
scala> foo(bar)
res0: Int = 3
scala> foo(bar _)
res1: Int = 3
scala> foo((i) => bar(i))
res2: Int = 3
```